# UML Diagram with interface

Tags: java, uml

I need to create UML diagram for my program, car park, I'am not sure what to do after I have designed those classes. The program is constructed out of  7 classes.

```
Vehicle implements Comparable<Vehicle>
Car extends Vehicle
Van extends Vehicle
Motorbike extends Vehicle
interface CarPark
CarParkManager implements CarPark
DateTime
```

Right now im not sure how and where to add those remaining classes or if they should be connected to the vehicle ? Any tips on that ?

Comment: A CarPark is probably dealing with some 0 to n Vehicles. So there is some usage there, but on a first glance, I wouldn't see any other direct relations.

Comment: You need to tell what you want to do with those remaining classes. Why did you "invent" them? What are those `extend` labeled associations? I guess you meant a generalization.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Note that

- Full arrow with empty head is extension
- Stripped arrow with empty head is implementation

If I don't mind all the fields, I'd draw roughly something like this:

[image]

Comment: Your realize is the wrong way. The class realizes and interface. Not vice versa. Further, the Extends label in the generalization is, well, uncommon. What does that tell?

Comment: Nikolas Charalambidis - Good explanation! However, there is a drawing mistake (the word for a typing mistake is often called typo but I do not know what word I use for a drawing mistake) as already pointed out by qwerty_so.  Revert the arrow between Vehicle & Comparable and between CarPark & CarParkManager.

Comment: This is the best answer but the error in the arrow direction spoils it

Answer (score 0):

UML has several diagrams. 
Now you're trying to represent "class Diagram"  [some info](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_diagram)

My advice are:

1) to represent the carpark and the carpark Manager as you did for the problem of vehicles.

2) rappresent DateTime if is important (if is a general and common class in your development environment, you can avoid it)

3) use relationships of association if there is a communication between one class and another, or agregation/compensition if some clase have other classes.

some consideration:

1) uml is not an exact science but a method of representing the conceptual reality of your system, so try to keep the level of detail to make it useful to the programmer that read it!

2)class diaframs are used to describe how classes are made, and not why or how they work. (the names you use can definitely give a perception of this, but other schemes exist to do this)

3)you should consider the idea of submitting a use case diagram,before the class diagram presentation

4) if the system is very complex and you want to keep a good record of what happens, then, as a final document, you may think of a sequence diagram